# logging не выдает сообщения в консоль

Tags: python, aiogram, логирование

пишу телеграм бот на aiogram

```
import logging

storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

в консоли ни одного сообщения нет
пробовал в файл писать файлы тоже пустые
хотел переустановить logging
выходит ошибка.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что в приведенном коде просто нечего логировать. Попробуйте пример из документации: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/quick_start.html#summary. Ну и возможно порядок команд действительно важен

Comment: естественно код не весь. пробовал создать другую папку с виртуальным окружением, не сработало.

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с этим разделом справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Код в вопрос нужно добавлять не просто "чтобы было", а чтобы его можно было запустить и воспроизвести у себя такую же проблему. Вы, получается, даете обрубок кода, на котором проблема точно не воспроизведется (логгер точно не сработает), таким образом вводя других участников в заблуждение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка по не внимательности (мой бич)
был подключен модуль в котором уже импортировался `logging`
Решено!

Comment: А можно подробнее, что было сделано? У меня кажется похожая проблема

Comment: оказалось  у меня был импортирован мой же модуль в котором вызывался logging, вышло так что logging вызывался 2 раза. удалил строку с вызовом logging из импортированного модуля и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Дело в том, что у логирования уровень "выставляется" в 2-х местах. Сперва у логера, а потом у отображающего собщения хэндлера, `basicConfig` конфигурирует хэндлер, а дефолтный логер по-прежнему `info, debug` не отображает.

P.S. `setLevel` работает... А вот попытался менять `level` в `basicConfig` что-то оно не влияет, надо разбираться. А вообще-то в `basicConfig` всего-всего понапихано, лучше логер и хэндлер отдельно формировать.